# Asynchrous copy-file and copy-directory in Emacs-Lisp?

Tags: file, emacs, directory

Does it exists functions for *Emacs Lisp* which can copy files and directories (with support for **TRAMP**) and does this asynchronously?

My problem is that `(copy-file)` and `(copy-directory)` blocks my editor until they finish and if I do it over **TRAMP** with a remote-server it takes about 5-10 seconds until I can proceed.

Comment: I've never used it myself but maybe [emacs-deferred](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-deferred) could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer to this myself, I use
[emacs-async](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-async) like this:

```
(async-start
    `(lambda()
        (copy-file ,local ,remote-path t t)
        ,local)
    (lambda(return-path)
        (message "Upload '%s' finished" return-path))))
```

Place your paths in the variables `local` and `remote-path`. For directories, just change `(copy-file)` to `(copy-directory)`.

Also I think you can use [emacs-deferred](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-deferred) too, however I haven't tried it yet.