# Asynchronous copy-directory with the option to ignore subdirectory in Emacs-lisp?

Tags: file, emacs, directory

I am using the code from the answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504796/asynchrous-copy-file-and-copy-directory-in-emacs-lisp) problem for asynchronous copy-directory for a few months now, but sometimes I need one or more subdirectories to be ignored. Is there an easy way by slightly modifying the code to do that?

I have tried to use Selective Directory Copying: SDC package from [here](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/emacs-lisp/selective-directory-copying/), but it brakes when file or folder already exists.

This is the code I am using right now:

```lisp
(async-start
    `(lambda()
        (copy-directory ,"~/Documents/data/" ,"~/Dropbox/data_backup/" t t t)
        ,"~/Documents/data/")
    (lambda(return-path)
        (message "Upload '%s' finished" return-path)))
```

There is a subdirectory in `~/Documents/data` that sometimes I want it to be ignored because it is larger than a threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy-directory` calls itself recursively.  You can use `cl-flet` to redefine it locally, while keeping the original definition.  You can also do this with advice (and actually this `cl-flet` technique seems to break advice), but then it's effectively globally redefining the function and you need to control it with e.g. variables.

```
(defun jpk/copy-directory (directory newname &optional keep-time parents copy-contents)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'orig/copy-directory) (symbol-function 'copy-directory))
            ((symbol-function 'copy-directory)
             (lambda (directory newname &optional keep-time parents copy-contents)
               (if (string= directory "/path/to/foo")
                   (message "skipping: %s" directory)
                 (orig/copy-directory directory newname keep-time parents copy-contents)))))
    (copy-directory directory newname keep-time parents copy-contents)))
```

In more detail: store the original function to `orig/copy-directory`, replace the function `copy-directory` with a lambda that calls `orig/copy-directory` only if the directory name doesn't match some string, then call the new definition of `copy-directory`.  The recursive call to `copy-directory` also uses the new definition.  All of this is wrapped up in `jpk/copy-directory`.  To make it more flexible, you could add a predicate argument to `jpk/copy-directory` so the test isn't hard coded.